# How do pushpool and stratum-minig-litcoin format the shares they send to the pool

Tags: pushpool, stratum

I just build up a mining pool using booth pushpool for getwork and stratum-mining-litcoin for stratum

we already finds block using getwork but nothing with miners using stratum.
So I check my shares tables in the database and notice that the hash submited by pushpool and stratum was not the same

How can I be sur that the shares submitted by stratum are valid ?

I look for some documentation in the [github repo of stratum-mining-litcoin](https://github.com/moopless/stratum-mining-litecoin) but found nothing.